# Assigning multiple variables to a single in PHP

Tags: php, meta-tags

What I want to do is call all of my meta tags from one variable kept in the variables.php file.

I can echo them individually but I want to assign them all the same name so the echo script in the webpage is smaller. I understand that this is how you assign the same value to an integer but I cannot find the solution to do this with string values(I think they are string right?)

```
$john = $ jane = 3;
```

What I am trying.

```
$metaAuthor = $metaDescription = $metaImage = $metaTitle =$meta;
```

I assume its a different command when you are not using numbers?

Comment: so the `metaAuthor` is the same as the description and title.. etc?

Comment: Rather so that $meta represents all the other values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same for every datatype, strings, ints, arrays, etc work all the same.

A little demo here:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/325104e0194b11b98fd7df58953aec4b0deb1468

Af of your comment you probably want this:

```
$meta = $metaAuthor." ".$metaDescription." ".$metaImage ." ".$metaTitle;
```

An array works like this:

```
$meta = array("author" => $metaAuthor, "description" => $metaDescription );
echo $meta['author'];
```

Comment: So they all take on the value of $meta but this doesn't give $meta their value! How do I give $meta all of their values, can that be done?

Comment: than you will need to use an array. Or if you want to have it all in one string: `$meta = $metaAuthor." ".metaDescription." ".$metaImage ." ".$metaTitle;`

Answer (score 1):

No it is the same with every value type.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9211ff6bebf264fa106c28a85d789b8fb6b42c99

```
<?php
$meta = 'TEST';
$metaAuthor = $metaDescription = $metaImage = $metaTitle = $meta;
echo $metaAuthor."\n"; 
echo $metaDescription."\n";
echo $metaImage."\n";
echo $metaTitle."\n";
echo $meta."\n";
// all variables have now become equal to $meta
```

Comment: How come I receive no output when I echo $meta? Is it becuase I am assigning a variable

Comment: probably because your not setting a value to it. It goes from right to left such that `$x = $y = $z;`  All variables will become equal to `$z`

Comment: Yea you're right. What I want to do is make $meta represent all of the others values.

Comment: Then just switch the variable order around so that the last one is the one you want all the others to be.

Answer (score 0):

Your code SHOULD assign whatever value is in `$meta` to all the other variables. In PHP, the "return value" or result of an assignment is the value being assigned. As long as $meta contains something, that something should be assigned everywhere else as well.

e.g.

```
php > $x = $y = $z = 7;
php > var_dump($x, $y, $z);
int(7)
int(7)
int(7)
php > $a = $b = $c = 'hello';
php > var_dump($a,$b,$c);
string(5) "hello"
string(5) "hello"
string(5) "hello"
php >
```