# how to assign multiple variables into single one?

Tags: php, variables

while trying this, I get error. is there a way to do it? I can assign multiple strings to a single variable but I don't know why it doesn't work with another variables.

```
$var1 = "Hello";
$var2 = "There";

$var3 = $var1, $var2;

echo $var3,  "<br />";
```

Comment: Have a look at these questions

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163596/assigning-multiple-variables-to-a-single-in-php][1]


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057229/php-assigning-multiple-strings-to-a-single-variable][2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use concat like this:

(Or maybe you just made a typo because `,` is directly to the left of `.`)

```
$var1 = "Hello";
$var2 = "There";

$var3 = $var1 . " " . $var2;

echo $var3 . "<br />";
```

See for further reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php